# Как удалить записи событий в vSphere Client

Tags: события, vmware

Как можно выборочно удалить записи на вкладке "События" в vSphere Client.
Система VmWare Esxi 5.5.  VCenter не развернут.

Comment: а в какой именно БД вы храните хроники esxi?

Comment: напоминаю, что логи автоматически чистятся после 24ч

Comment: Установкой esxi я не занимался. Как можно это определить, имея доступ по ssh например?

Comment: просто перезагрузите ESXi и проверьте. эвенты должны исчезнуть

Comment: После перезагрузки все события остались.

Comment: подожди. иы про vSphere Client говоришь или esxi server? если клиент, то нужно выйти и зайти заного.

Comment: Еще раз проверил. Стираются все события,  которые были до перезагрузки сервера esxi. Но это для меня это решение неприемлимо. Мне нужно определить как и где хранятся эти события и удалить некоторые из них. Например, что какой-то хост был выключен или включен. 2. Чтобы посмотреть события я запускаю vSphere Client и соединяюсь с сервером esxi 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

нет никакой возможности удалить Events, Tasks из системы. Все это храниться в базе данных, к которой нет доступа. Конечно, если вы не взломали базу данных.

но можно их все почистить так, чтобы через консоль не были видны.

если есть доступ к самой машине с клавиатурой, то Console Menu - Restart  Network Management Agents.

или выполнить удаленно через SSH

```
/sbin/services.sh restart
```

Это никак не затронет работу VM. Эвенты не удалит из самой БД для будущего аудита, но позволит очистить ВСЕ события и таски из UI